# Pre define toolbars in CKEditor5

Tags: ckeditor5

I'm using the following code to implement a CKeditor5 editor on my page

```
ClassicEditor
            .create( document.querySelector("#editor"), {
                toolbar: ['heading', '|',
                    {
                        label: 'Basic Settings',
                        icon: false,
                        items: [ 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'strikethrough', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'link', 'outdent', 'indent', 'fontSize', 'fontFamily', 'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor' ]
                    },
                    '|',
                    {
                        label: 'Media',
                        icon: false,
                        items: [ 'uploadImage', 'insertTable', 'mediaEmbed' ]
                    },
                    '|',
                    'alignment', 'code', 'selectAll', 'removeFormat', 'findAndReplace', 'undo', 'redo', 'sourceEditing'
                ]
            } )
            .catch( error => {
                console.log( error );
            } );
```

I'm going to be using this editor in muliple place within my site and there will be slightly different versions of the toolbar that I'd like to implement. Is it possible fo me to define the toolbars in a different file and reference them in this create call? i.e

```
ClassicEditor
            .create( document.querySelector("#editor"), {
                toolbar: 'baiscToolbar'
            } )
            .catch( error => {
                console.log( error );
            } );
```

or

```
ClassicEditor
            .create( document.querySelector("#editor"), {
                toolbar: 'advancedToolbar'
            } )
            .catch( error => {
                console.log( error );
            } );
```

Answer (score 0):

could this solution can help you,

```
    // create an array of your tools needed
    var basicTools = ['undo', 'redo', '|','bulletedList', 'numberedList', '|','bold', 'italic', 'style'];
    ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector("#editor"), {
            toolbar:  {
                items: basicTolls,
            }
        } )
        .catch( error => {
            console.log( error );
        } );
```